# Windows Event viewer log XML to CSV

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

im trying to write a basic script to extract the XML from a Windows event log for bootTime and get multiple machines to append to 1 file ready to be imported into a database.

Current script:

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Diagnostics-Performance/Operational"; id=100}
$event1 = [xml]$events[0].ToXml()
$event2 = [xml]$events[0].ToXml()
$event1.Event.eventdata.data |Export-Csv "C:\data.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
$event2.Event.System.Computer |Out-File "C:\data.csv" -Append -Force
```

End result is to have a column at the start of the CSV which has the computer name and then other 2 columns to have the data from the output.

The only way i can get the Computer name to appear within the same file is to make it an Out-File which i know is the incorrect output as it needs to be CSV.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solves your problem:

```
$dataToExport = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
$dataToExport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Computer -Value $event2.Event.System.Computer
$dataToExport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Data -Value $even1.Event.eventdata.data
$dataToExport | Export-Csv "C:\data.csv"
```